# how to see grub kernels in ubuntu without restarting

Tags: grub2, kernel

I want to set up my ubuntu server to boot from an older kernel since the current one causes problems.

How do i see the list of entries in the grub menu so i know which one to set to GRUB_DEFAULT? Without restarting. It`s a remote server and i`d rather not drive 30 kms to see a list.

Comment: Look in `/boot` for the `initrd.img-*` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for menuentry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry
```